# Outlook "to" internal email addresses resolving to X500 Exchange Addresses after an email is created via Quick Step

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

In Outlook 2013 using Exchange Office 365, I have created a Quick Step to enable me to quickly email all my colleagues within the business. This is very simply set up (In Quick Steps click on "Create New", Name "Team Email", Choose an Action "New Message", type all the relevant emails in the "To" box).

However whenever I use this quick step all the emails in the "To" box of my new message display as [what I understand are "EX" or "X500" addresses](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e78bd9ad-4ec3-4f2d-9939-747cafe77faa/how-to-resolve-the-email-address-in-this-form-oabcdouexchange-administrative-group?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment). They take the following sort of form:

```
/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (AAAAAAAA111AAA)/cn=Recipients/cn=aaa1aa1a111a1a11-John.Doe
```

In terms of functionality this is not an issue at all. In terms of appearance and ease of use (e.g. if I want to remove one or two emails from the list) it is extremely annoying because it makes it so difficult to see which email address is which.

Furthermore, any email I manually create, after having used the Quick Step, which is sent to one of those recipients, always displays the EX/X500 email address in the "To" box. Again this doesn't affect the functionality or deliverability of the message but it looks very untidy.

The only workaround I have found is to delete the Auto Suggest entry whenever it displays the EX/X500 email address and re-type it manually. Although time consuming this is OK but as soon as I re-use the Quick Step again the problem recurs.

I believe this is a bug in Outlook 2013 (can't speak for any other versions), but can anyone help resolve the issue?

I have tried

1. Searching online without results - but I may be searching for the wrong terminology
2. Outlook repair, both basic and full
3. Completely reinstalling Office 2013 on a new computer
4. Re-typing the Quick Step "to" entries
5. Completely deleting the Quick Step and recreating it
6. Creating a new Outlook Profile.

Using Windows 10, Outlook 2013 32-bit on Exchange Office 365.